# ui-router does not see url search params after page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a state that looks like something like this

```
.state('home.foo.bar', {
  url: 'view?one&two',
  views: {
    'base': {
      templateUrl: 'blah',
      controller: 'blahCtrl'
    }
  },
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

if I navigate to this state in my template with

```
ui-sref="home.foo.bar({one: valueOne, two: valueTwo})"
```

all is well and the url is

> .com/view?one=valueOne&two=valueTwo

however if I refresh the page the url changes to just .com/view and neither `$state.params` or `$stateParams` contains the values.

if I add a resolve step like so

```
.state('home.foo.bar', {
  url: 'view?one&two',
  views: {
    'base': {
      templateUrl: 'blah',
      controller: 'blahCtrl'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    p: function($location, $stateParams, $state) {
      console.log($location.search(), $stateParams, $state);
      if(!$stateParams.one && !$stateParams.two {
        $stateParams.one = $location.search().one;
        $stateParams.two = $location.search().two;
      } else {
        return $location.search().one;
      }
    }
  },
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

then when I initially navigation to the state in my template the log statement prints nothing for `$location.search()` but shows `oneValue` and `twoValue` in the `$stateParams` and `$state.params`.  When I refresh its opposite `$location.search()` shows the parameters and their values correctly but `$stateParams` and `$state.params` are empty.

adding the if statement and setting the values explicitly resolves my bug but this cant be working as intended can it?

am I missing something obvious?

Comment: looks like you need to look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1079

Comment: Thank-you for your reply,  I have read through that thread but I don't think it is the same problem I am referring to here.  They are all talking about problems when navigating between states.  I am talking about a problem when I refresh the browser page itself so the angular app in its entirety is being reloaded from scratch

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because you are missing a slash at the beginning or your URL:

```
.state('home.foo.bar', {
  url: '/view?one&two',
  views: {
    'base': {
      templateUrl: 'blah',
      controller: 'blahCtrl'
    }
  },
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

Comment: Thanks but these states actually extend another base route whose url ends with a slash.  Do you still think that could be the problem?

Comment: I think this is the problem. Try by keeping the trailing slash on the parent, I am not sure if it will add a double slash. If it does, remove the trailing slash on the parent and set strictMode to false.

Comment: But even with a slash, we experience this behavior!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However it turned out that the problem is not `angular`. Check your routing on the server, there may change `url`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I interfered the regular statechange/statestart/statesuccess
so in my resolving in statesuccess I have added:

```
 //$state.go(toState,toParams);
 //when I manupulated the regular ui-router params 
 $state.go($rootScope.toState,$rootScope.toParams);
```

So ve aware of passing toParams when you change the regular ui-router parameters control.